# Node-Red - Get all nodes connected to another node

Tags: node.js, node-red

Is there any way to know which nodes are connected to another without any messages passing along?

As an example, right now I have a node that creates a list of devices connected to it, which is updated whenever a new message reaches it.

Can I access all the nodes that are connected to the input of that main node and create the list based on names, topics, whatver the other nodes have when I deploy, instead of having to wait for messages?

Answer (score 1):

No, this goes against the spirit of flow based programming, no node should care what other nodes are connected to it.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess that's fair enough.